# How do I intercept a request and store the response using Selenium 4's BiDi API in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, bidi

I'm exploring the new NetworkInterceptor class but every example I've seen is for modifying the request. What I'm attempting to do is intercept background REST API calls a page makes while loading and store the JSON responses as strings.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.